# Androidアプリでgooglemapのマーカーアイコンの中心と座標の位置を合わせたい。

Tags: android, google-maps

Androidアプリ内に実装したgooglemapで、タップした位置に点を表示させたいです。
マーカーを専用の丸画像に差し替えて表示しようとしましたが、画像の下部の位置にタップした位置がきてしまいます。
画像の中心（マーカーの中心）をタップした座標の位置にしたいのですが、そういったオプションは存在するのでしょうか。

もしくはマーカー以外の良い方法があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

[image: 通常は黒矢印の位置がタップした座標ですが、緑矢印の位置の様に、マーカーの中心がタップした位置になるようにしたいです。]

通常は黒矢印の位置がタップした座標ですが、緑矢印の位置の様に、マーカーの中心がタップした位置になるようにしたいです。

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの質問は `anchor(0.5f,0.5f)` を追加することで解決いたしました。